# Can my muslim husband have a friendship with an older woman, because she is like his mother?

Tags: halal-haram, husband-wife, relationships, friendship

What relationships are lawful in Islam with husband and wife? Can my husband be in friendship with another women and give the excuse, that she is just like his mother? Is this permissible in Islam?

I mean friendship, helping her with her personal problems, visiting her alone in her apartment, she is 19 years older than him. What I understand: it is completely haraam, but my husband says she is like his mother.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by *relationship* and *friendship* and perhaps also on exactly how much older the women are.  A man should not be alone with a non-mahram woman.

Comment: I mean friendship, helping her with her personal problems, visiting her alone in her apartment, she is 19 years older than him. What i understand it is completely haraam but my husbands says she is like his mother.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE.  It's best to respond to comments by [edit]ing the question.  I did it in this case.

Answer (score 3):

A woman can not be *like a mother* to someone by just his saying that. A man and a woman can not be alone with each other, unless they are *[mahrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahram)*: this is a bond that is due to a blood relation, marriage or fosterage by suckling and not something established by uttering a phrase.

A man and a woman must properly cover themselves infront of non-mahrams, and a non-mahrams are not allowed to be alone with each other.

> No person (man) should be alone with a woman except when there is a
>   Mahram with her.
>   [[Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/15/478) and [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/56/215) ]
>
> A man is not alone with a woman but the third of them is Ash-Shaitan (Satan). [ [Tirmizi](https://sunnah.com/urn/674690) ]

Tell your husband that he can not be alone with a non-mahram woman and tell him to take you with him when he visits her to solve her personal problems.